# Why does Elastic Search return this record?

Tags: elasticsearch

Executive summary - why is this Elastic Search query...

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "document.company_id": 197
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "change.company_id": 197
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "missing": {
                                            "field": "document.company_id"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "missing": {
                                            "field": "changes.company_id"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "user.id": [
                                                2165, 2976, ...
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                                ... (closing braces here on)
```

...returning this record?

```
"_source" : {
    "date" : "2015-03-27T09:36:41.716+00:00",
    "change" : {
       "company_id" : 12,
       "id" : "CC-12-51"
    },
    "action" : "change-control-approved",
    "description" : "blah blah",
    "user" : {
       "full_name" : "Martin Wtorkowski",
       "email" : "mwtorkowski@getzendoc.com",
       "id" : 40
    },
    "_date" : 1427445401,
    "id" : 57879,
    "invalid" : null
 },
```

Given the fact that `must` corresponds to `AND` and `should` corresponds to `OR`, ...

- The record doesn't have a `document.company_id` of 197 (so the first OR term doesn't apply)
- The record doesn't have a `change.company_id` of 197 (it has a `change.company_id` of 12 - so the second OR term doesn't apply either)
- The third term says: `MUST` (therefore `AND`) for 3 conditions: (a) field `document.company_id` must be missing - and it is indeed missing (b) field `change.company_id` must be missing - *and IT IS NOT MISSING* (c) field `user.id` must have one of a set of values.

I am probably missing some intricate detail of the ES API - but since the 2nd of the 3 `must` conditions fails, this record should not have passed.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you have a typo in your second `missing` filter, i.e. `changes.company_id` instead of `change.company_id`. Can you check if that fixes?

Comment: Oh God - that was it. Thanks, Val... (sigh) I *so* miss static type checks in these APIs... P.S. Add your answer below so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `missing` filter, there's a typo.

If you modify `changes.company_id` to `change.company_id`, it should work as expected.